# Ethers js deploy contract with balance, payable constructor

Tags: contract-deployment, javascript, payable, constructor, ethers.js

I have a smart contract with a payable constructor. I'm trying to figure out the syntax with ethers js how I can deploy the smart contract and send an initial balance with the deployment.

```
const initialBalance = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1");
const myContract = await ethers.getContractFactory('MyContract');   
const deployedContract = await myContract.deploy(initialBalance);
```

The above gives me an error, I assume because it's reading the initialBalance as an argument to the constructor and my constructor takes in no arguments. How can I send an initial balance during deployment like you can from the Remix IDE? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Just change `initialBalance` to `{ value: initialBalance }`

```
const deployedContract = await myContract.deploy({ value: initialBalance });
```

The deploy function takes constructor arguments followed by an optional argument called overrides object ([docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract-factory/#ContractFactory-deploy)). If your function is payable, then you are allowed to use the `value` override. You can see [list of overrides](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-functionsSend).

Comment: how about Ethers.js v6. Are those https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/contract/#Overrides ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet if you are using ethers.js v6

```
const initialBalance = ethers.parseEther("0.1");
const myContract = await ethers.deployContract("MyContract",{value: initialBalance});
await myContract.waitForDeployement();
```