# Send eth by deploying a Contract ( Ethers.js )

Tags: contract-development, ether, contract-deployment, ethers.js, sendtransaction

Is there a way to send eth to another wallet at the same time with deploying smart contract?

```
let factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, signer);
            const contract = await factory.deploy();
```

Comment: Does this help ? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/106299/ethers-js-deploy-contract-with-balance-payable-constructor

Comment: no, :(

I mean creating a contract and send eth to another address in one transaction. 
------
Example:
Deploy contract by signer ------
transfer 0.01 eth from: Wallet signer   to: Wallet address

------
by await factory.deploy();

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that the ETH transfer happens when deploying the Smart Contract, your approach should be as follow:

1. Create an Smart Contract with a Payable Constructor
2. Make the constructor transfer ETH to the desired wallet address.
3. Send ETH to the Smart Contract at deployment.

This should work for you. It transfers the given amount in the deployment (msg.value) to the desired receiver (input param of the constructor):

```
contract PayContract {

    constructor(address receiver) payable {
        (bool sentValue, ) = receiver.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(sentValue, "Failed to send the amount to the receiver.");
    }

}
```

Comment: the sender must create a contract and send some Ethereum to another address in one transaction. 

with ethers.js

Comment: That's what my example does. When you deploy that contract, Metamask will ask you to provide ETH, that will be managed by the constructor function.

Comment: how to call this with the deploy function?

Comment: Add {value: int}, as the last input param of the constructor.